# If $f(n) \geq g(n)$ for all $n \geq n_0$ then $f(n) \geq cg(n)$ for all $n \geq n_1$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

So I've thought of this statement which I'd like to know if it's true but I can't seem to prove it:

If there exists a number $n_0$ such that $$f(n) \geq g(n)$$ for all $n \geq n_0$

then there is a number $n_1$ such that $$f(n) \geq cg(n)$$  for all $n \geq n_1 $ and some $c \in \mathbb{R}^+$

Now I'm sure it holds but I can't seem to produce a formal, concise and direct proof. Also to clarify $n,n_1,n_2 \in \mathbb{N}$.

**Explanation:** So what I'm basically saying is that $f$ eventually becomes "larger" than $g$ even when $g$ is scaled. I know I'm probably rephrasing something that has been said before but I'm really interested in seeing how this turns out. Also, I know this looks like the definition of big-O notation which is what I saw in the class from where I got this. Sorta to facilitate a proof I was doing in class. Hehe.

Edit: Title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement as you have given it is trivially true when $c=1$.  If you insist on having $c>1$ then it is not true: take, for example,
$$f(n)=n+1\quad\hbox{and}\quad g(n)=n\ .$$

Comment: Hmm... I knew that for 0<c<1 and c = 1 it would hold. But is there a way to get $f(n) \geq g(n)$? What kind of restriction should one add?

Comment: $ 0<c \leq \frac{f(n_1)}{g(n_1)}$?